# How to know if a Date object represents only Time in Java?

Tags: java, date, time, format

I'm trying to save data about date and time to List. Let's say, I have `List<Date>`. I have 2 types of formatting of strings: `dd/mm/yy` and `hh:mm`. Well, I'm able to easily format and create an instance of `java.util.Date` using `SimpleDateFormat`. However, when I try to print the object, the one that I saved time data into prints something like this:

> Thu Jan 01 06:30:00 AZT 1970

How do I differentiate between these two and get the following output instead:

> 06:30

Note: Years may start earlier than 1970.

Thanks for the help and appreciate the effort.

Comment: I suggest you don't use `Date` for two different things (or at all). You can use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) for the times and [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for the dates.

Comment: @khelwood there is a Super Class for those 2, I'm assuming?

Comment: Why would you want there to be a superclass?  You never want to mix those up.

Comment: Date objects dot not have a concept of formatting - they are containers for the amount of time which has passed since a given poking in time ( ie the Unix epoch), this is why we have date formatters

Comment: They both implement Temporal, and other interfaces, as you can see in the documentation. Whether that is useful depends on what you actually need to do to with the objects. Since you evidently need to tell them apart, trying to conflate them does not seem to be benefitting you.

Comment: The superclass is needed because I will be comparing them later on. Of course, date with date, and time with time respectively.

Comment: Alright, I understood what you guys meant. I'm thinking of creating my own object that extends the Native one with the extra variable for differentiating.

Comment: Thanks @khelwood and @ MadProgrammer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to know if a Date object represents only Time in Java?

There is no way to do this reliably.  Every value of `Date` that you are using to represent a time *also* represents a valid date.  And you can't distinguish the two cases ... except by using an *unreliable* heuristic.

The real problem is that you should not use `Date` to represent times.

- A `Date` represents a single point in the time continuum.
- A time is either a duration or multiple time points depending on how you use it.  (It depends on your use-case.)

---

In fact, you probably not be using `java.util.Date` at all.  `Date` is legacy Java class that has many API flaws.  It was superseded in Java 8 by the classes and interfaces in the `java.time` package.  These provide distinct classes for the various different concepts.

I recommend that you read the [Date-Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) trail in the Oracle Java Tutorial to get a basic understanding.  This will help you decide the correct classes to choose for your use-case.

Time is complicated in the real world, and it is complicated in Java too.